# qmake assigning variables in command line

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qmake

I am having trouble understanding how assignments in the command line work.

when I run:

```
qmake-qt4 -project -o project.pro
qmake-qt4 -o qMakeFile "CFLAGS += -std=c++11"
make -f qMakeFile
```

and after the qMakeFile is make, CFLAGS is unchanged.

I'm sure it's something obvious I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in here:

- You are trying to set a C++ option for the CFLAGS variable as opposed to CXXFLAGS.
- if I were, I would pass the `"CFLAGS+=-std=c++11"` to the first qmake run when the project file is created because the variable will be put into the generated qmake file, then, rather than just into the Makefile with your current approach.

This would useful in the sense that when you re-run qmake for some reason, you do not need to pass the `CFLAGS` explicitly all the time to make sure it will be in your Makefile.

- Furthermore, you should consider using the `QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable instead of raw `CXXFLAGS` in a qmake project file.
- Even furthermore, qmake has better support for c++11 through the `CONFIG1` variable.
- Another thing is that I would personally remove the needless extra spaces around the appending assignment. If you check out, this generates needless extra spaces in the Makefile, which then need to be escaped and so on.
- Also, I am not sure why you need to generate custom Makefile name.

I would personally just write something like this:

```
qmake -project "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11" # only executed once
```

or this is even more recommended:

```
qmake -project "CONFIG+=c++11" # only executed once

qmake && make
```

Please make sure you have a recent enough compiler version that supports this option and C++11 in general. Sometimes, people fall into the trap that they do not notice they would be using an old version that did not support it for the time.